# .NET Configuration files in library Projects

Tags: .net, configuration, app-config

I have several projects in my solution file and one of them happens to hold much of common logic applied across all the other client applications. Rather than have to replicate the same configuration settings in all the application configs, I have instead chosen to add a configuration file to my common library project. However, when I go to run any of the client projects, I get errors indicating that the information contained in configuration is missing. Essentially, the client instance, even though it holds a reference to the common library project, remains blind to the contents of the contents of the common library configuration file. What do I need to do to enable the use of both the client project's app.config contents as well as the common library's app.config contents?

**Note: that many of the "ANSWERS" before now(e,g .NET - Storing An App.config With A Class Library) assume that one is still using .NET 1.1 ConfigurationSettings manager instead of the ConfigurationManager. I am looking for answers that would work best for 3.5 and above.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET - Storing An App.config With A Class Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096872/net-storing-an-app-config-with-a-class-library)

Answer (score 0):

When you run an application using a library, it is the config file associated to the application that is used, the config file associated to your library will not.

So the config file of the application must contain the required configuration for all librairies associated.

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y.aspx) for details.

You could use a post build event to output an application config file that would automatically contain the content of satellites config files although I hope there are better tricks existing (that I don't know) for your issue.

Comment: do you have a sample of a post build event sample that could help me with writing mine to merge the contents of the common library config file with that of the application.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. I guess it may be possible with some software able to merge XML files but I don't know if there is a concrete solution existing based on this for your problem. You could still have two config file, one for the app. only settings and one containing all settings needed at run time and copy the second one in the post build event using batch script.